# Xml to Json liquid template stopped working on Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, liquid-template

After one month of successful mapping our template gives different results with no change in the process.
Xml fragment is as follows:

```html
  <Authorisation>
    <Application>
    </Application>
    <Role>Role on</Role>
    <Role>Role two</Role>
  </Authorisation>
```

and the mapping:

```
        "roles":[
            {% JSONArrayFor userRole in authorisation where Role-%}
            {
            "role":"{{userRole}}"
            }
            {% endJSONArrayFor -%}
        ]
```

The Logic App used to produce proper json collection but now, all of the sudden the collection
is empty.

I can see that authorisation.Role produces just first item "Role one"
and autorisation.Role.size gives 11.
For loop instead of JSONArrayFor read "role one" char by char.It all means that mapping only reads first role element - there is no collection

The problem is only for Xml simple type (just xml element with string value).
We process complex types in the same manner and it is still ok.

Is something internal in Azure LogicApps that has changed the mapping process last month?

Comment: Hi, please refer to the solution I provided below. If it helps your problem, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it as answer(click on the check mark beside my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thanks in advance~

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply but it is not a solution. I already had similar workaround in a form of a much simpler Xml transformation without json conversion. Ultimately this bug has been solved by LogicApp team

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a bug in MS and has been fixed

Answer (score 1):

It seems `where Role` in liquid doesn't work. I'm not sure if it work in the past, but I usually convert the xml to json first and then convert json to json if I want to implement this requirement. I provide my solution below for your reference:

**1.** I initialize a variable named `xmlString` to store the same xml as your xml data.
[image]

**2.** Then I initialize another variable named `jsonString` and input an expression into its value box (to convert the xml to json).
[image]

**3.** After that, parse the `jsonString` by "[Parse JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action)" action
[image]

**4.** At last, use "[Transform JSON to JSON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-liquid-transform)" to transform the `jsonString` to the format you want.
[image]

My liquid map is:

```
{% assign items = content.Authorisation.Role %}
{
    "roles": [
        {%- for item in items -%}
            {
                "role": "{{item}}"
            },
        {%- endfor -%}
    ]
}
```

**5.** Run the logic app, get the result shown as below:
[image]

Comment: Yes where filter is supposed to work. We do have a regression test for the same in our code base, doing a filter on a complex xml element name. Our engineers are investigating why for this specific use as reported here it isn't currently working.

Comment: This is ok when you send two or more items in role, but if you send only one role then it is a problem that automatic conversion to JSON will declare it as a object not an array and your Parse JSON will fail.
Best thing is to use Liquid transformation in that case because you can not know if someone will send one or more roles.